# MATLAB: Duplicate each element of a vector?

Tags: matlab, vector, matlab-guide, dimensional

I'm new to MATLAB and this website as well. I tried searching for this question, but to no avail (so I apologize if this ends up being a questions which has already been asked here before). In class, we were assigned a problem with the following description: "For an n-dimensional vector X, the function should return another 2n-dimension where each element is repeated twice. For example: if a=[2 3 4 5], after using the function, a=[2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5];"
It should work with a vector of ANY random size.

Your help is really appreciated! 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`kron`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html):

`K = kron(X,Y)` returns the Kronecker tensor product of X and Y. The result is a large array formed by taking all possible products between the elements of X and those of Y. If X is m-by-n and Y is p-by-q, then kron(X,Y) is m*p-by-n*q.

**In your case:**

```
kron(a,[1 1])
```

will give you what you wanted

Some alternatives answers for your question:

```
reshape([a ; a],1,[])

reshape([a'*[1 1]]',1,[])
```

Comment: I gave you already the general answer, namely `kron(x,y)`. play with `kron` input Y and see...

Comment: `1:n` is just `'[1 2 3 ...]' you need [1 1 1 1 .... ]` , use `ones(...`